# When I send mail it receives like array I want normal text

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

When I submit my contact form the data stored in mail as array format but, I want that data as normal text. In this code taken from google script for sending local mail. Can you please help me to solve this.

This is my output:

```
" {"name":["ganesh"],"message":["vndsjkvbkjd,v "],"email":["mine@gmail.com"]} "
```

I expect the output like

```
" name : ganesh , message : welcome , email : mine@gmail.com"
```

My code is given below:

```
function validEmail(email) { // see:
  var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
  return re.test(email);
}

// get all data in form and return object
function getFormData() {
  var elements = document.getElementById("gform").elements; // all form elements
  var fields = Object.keys(elements).filter(function(k){
    return k.length > 1 && elements[k].name && elements[k].name.length > 0 ;
  });
  var data = {};
  fields.forEach(function(k){
    data[k] = elements[k].value;
  });
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}

function handleFormSubmit(event) {  // handles form submit withtout any jquery
  event.preventDefault();           // we are submitting via xhr below
  var data = getFormData();         // get the values submitted in the form
  if( !validEmail(data.email) ) {   // if email is not valid show error
    document.getElementById('email-invalid').style.display = 'block';
    return false;
  } else {
    var url = event.target.action;  //
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    // xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log( xhr.status, xhr.statusText )
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        document.getElementById('gform').style.display = 'none'; // hide form
        document.getElementById('thankyou_message').style.display = 'block';
        return;
    };
    // url encode form data for sending as post data
    var encoded = Object.keys(data).map(function(k) {
        return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k])
    }).join('&')
    xhr.send(encoded);
  }
}

function loaded() {
  console.log('contact form submission handler loaded successfully');
  // bind to the submit event of our form
  var form = document.getElementById('gform');
  form.addEventListener("submit", handleFormSubmit, false);
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess that's just the output format and you probably can't change it.. what you can do is write a function that converts the output you are given to the output you want